# BOS token for encoder decoder models

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I’m using T5-base for my model, and it seems to be generating something reasonable when I do `model.generate`. But my question is how?

The decoder part of this model needs a starting token to start decoding doesn’t it? How does it figure out what the very first token is supposed to look like?

Or am I doing the training wrong where I should have included a token?

If needed [here is a code sample](https://www.kaggle.com/code/sachin/t5-for-grammar-correction) where I used `model.generate`.

### Edit 1

Apart from the answer below, I found that there was a `model.config.decoder_start_token_id`. This is not necessarily `<bos>`. In the case of `T5/Flan-T5` it ended up being `<pad>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already done within the `generate` method that is implemented using the [`GenerationMixin`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.24.0/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.generation_utils.GenerationMixin) in the PyTorch part of Huggingface Transformers. Even if you provide a prefix for the generation, the BOS (beginning of a sequence) token is [explicitly added](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.24.0/src/transformers/generation_utils.py#L510). The default generation algorithm is then the beam search.

Comment: But when I do model.config.bos_token it shows up as none. I'll take a look at the code in the morning. And thank you for now.